# I can't get my toggled classList styles to actually apply there styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning about classLists.toggle but for some reason I can't seem to get the element to actually apply
the toggled styles, I'm really struggling to figure out where I'm going wrong.
I'm using IDs with no current style so I can toggle a class on or off when clicked but can't figure out while there not applying, there getting the toggled style but not it's styles it's weird
could anyone explain why this is?

```js
const clicked = () => {
  document.getElementById("box").classList.toggle("toggle");
  document.getElementById("text").classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #42b883;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 70px;
  right: 750px;
}

#box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle #box {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onClick="clicked()"></div>
<h2 id="text">Test</h2>
```

Comment: For a question where something isn't working right, please post the code you are using that isn't working

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant to, it's there now.

Comment: wait, I thought toggle was a jQuery function?! LoL all those manual toggles I did XD

Answer (score 1):

Because your css rule is wrong.

```
.toggle #box {
```

should be

```
#box.toggle {
```

Your code is looking for

```
<div class="toggle">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: WHAT!? for real XD thanks haha I worte it like this in another line  .change #bar1{
 transform: translateY(0px) rotateZ(-50deg);
} For a hamburger menu and it worked?